# Storing multiple network devices in YAML and referrencing it in jinja2

Tags: yaml, jinja2

How do I construct a yaml file to hold multiple network devices and reference to a specific vendor/type from a jinja2 file?

For example:

```
—
ip: 10.10.10.10
hostname: core-fw-domain-location
username: admin
password: password
vendor: cisco
type: firewall
ip: 20.20.20.20
hostname: core-rt-domain-location
username: admin
password: password
vendor: cisco
type: router
```

The above obviously doesn't work - how do I structure it so it's hierarchal?

In my jinja2 file, how do I reference it?

For example:

```
{% if node.hostname == 'core-fw-domain-location' %}
enable secret {{ node.secret }}
username admin privilege password {{ node.secret }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure your YAML as a list of maps:

```
- ip: 10.10.10.10
  hostname: core-fw-domain-location
  username: admin
  password: password
  vendor: cisco
  type: firewall
- ip: 20.20.20.20
  hostname: core-rt-domain-location
  username: admin
  password: password
  vendor: cisco
  type: router
```

Then in your python code, change `node` to `nodes` when you render the template because there are now multiple nodes configured:

```
config = baseline.render(nodes = node_object)
```

And in your jinja2 file, loop through `nodes` accordingly:

```
{% for node in nodes -%}
{% if node.hostname == 'core-fw-domain-location' %}
enable secret {{ node.password }}
username admin privilege password {{ node.password }}
{% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: I see. I forgot that you now need to loop through the nodes since it's now more than just one. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked! Why did you need to put the hyphen at the end of the for loop -%} and beginning of of endfor {%-?

Comment: And just to confirm, it's treating each element in the list as a "node", correct?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Yes it loops through every item in `nodes` and assign the item to `node`, which in this case is a dict. The hyphen before the end of a jinja tag or after the start of a jinja tag means to strip any white spaces and newlines in that direction, so that there won't be unnecessary blank lines inserted into your rendered output.